# Raise exception without quitting the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, nameerror, raiseerror

I'm on Windows and using python 3.7.7. I am trying to make a golfing language. In that e. if you raise an Exception (to be clear `NameError`) like this:

```py
raise NameError("Your input was not recognized as a function, variable or  datatype")
```

Then the program automatically quits.
When I tried this:

```py
 print(NameError("Your input was not recognized as a function, variable or  datatype"))
```

Then it prints the error but not fully and not in red like this:
`Your input was not recognized as a function, variable or  datatype`

Is there a way that the program should not quit and print a real error?

Comment: And what should the program do after the error is printed?

Comment: If all you care about is color, then you can use a package like [colorize](https://pypi.org/project/colorize/)

Comment: Hi, have you considered using a try ... catch statement . If you provide an example of what you want to do it might be easy to show how the try catch statement fits it . Best regards

Comment: @wovano It should continue as normal

Comment: @MZ I tried all the coloring packages but it printed something like `hello[1]re[[3]`

Comment: @Tanmay, I don't think that's possible. The whole point of exceptions is that the normal program flow is interrupted, and the error is handled. If an exception is not catched, the Python interpreter will catch it and print the traceback and stop the thread (and if it's the last non-daemon thread it will stop the whole application).

Comment: @wovano using a `try except` (Python terminology for try-catch) would prevent the Python interpreter from reading it as an exception. Not all exceptions kill the program either

Comment: @MZ, that's true, but after catching an exception the program would not just continue where the exception occurred. That's why I asked what the program should do, and Tanmay answered "it should continue as normal". I'm not completely sure what the use case is and what problem we're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of more details, you can try something like this:

```
try:
    raise(NameError("Your input was not recognized as a function, variable or  datatype"))
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
```

However, this is not exactly how exceptions should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the Python termcolor module. Usage is pretty simple:

```py
from termcolor import colored
```

Python 2:

```py
print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
```

Or in Python 3:

```py
print(colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green'))
```

Along with the use of "try-except" statement, since after all, you can raise exceptions without quitting the program, by adding something in the except clause.

Comment: Although this might print a nicely colored error message, it does not really answer the question "Raise exception without quitting". It merely prints an (error) message. If that is the wanted functionality it might be a good solution for the OP, but then the question is a bit misleading IMHO.

Comment: NB: Is the Python 2 code really still needed? Python 2 is already past its extended end of life, and the question was tagged python-3.x.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this prints to me: ```[31mhello[0m [32mworld[0m```

Answer (score 0):

After long research I found an answer:
This doesn't raise an error but prints colored error in both terminal and shell

1. Install [CLINT](https://pypi.org/project/clint/) with pip

```sh
pip install clint
```

2. In Python

```py
import sys
try:
    sys.stdout.shell.write("Your input was not recognized as a variable, function or datatype\n", "COMMENT")
except AttributeError:
    puts(colored.red("Your input was not recognized as a variable, function or datatype"))
```